# Why am I getting null pointer exception? when adding value with static int

Tags: android, android-intent, static-variables

Please help I am almost done with my code, but when I run it I get nullpointerexception..
I am trying to increment a static int variable on button click,
their are five activities. In each activity their is a question, when answered correctly the static int must increment by 1. when last page is reached.. I display the total..

```
package com.example.kei;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.RadioButton;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    RadioButton correctChoice1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        correctChoice1.findViewById(R.id.correct1);
        correctChoice1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AppSingleton.score++;
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Page_two.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    public static class AppSingleton {

        public static int score= 0;
    }

    public void choice_a(View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Page_two.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }



    public void choice_c(View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Page_two.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

in the code **choice_a** and **choice_c** are wrong answers. i try to increment the correct answer with onlicklistener for radiobutton. why cant the code execute and give null pointer exception? please help.. i dont know what to do now..

LOGCAT:

```
03-25 05:21:04.811: D/dalvikvm(1052): Late-enabling CheckJNI
03-25 05:21:04.827: E/Trace(1052): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
03-25 05:21:04.863: D/AndroidRuntime(1052): Shutting down VM
03-25 05:21:04.863: W/dalvikvm(1052): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa6246288)
03-25 05:21:04.867: E/AndroidRuntime(1052): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-25 05:21:04.867: E/AndroidRuntime(1052): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.kei/com.example.kei.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-25 05:21:04.867: E/AndroidRuntime(1052):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
03-25 05:21:04.867: E/AndroidRuntime(1052):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
03-25 05:21:04.867: E/AndroidRuntime(1052):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
03-25 05:21:04.867: E/AndroidRuntime(1052):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
03-25 05:21:04.867: E/AndroidRuntime(1052):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-25 05:21:04.867: E/AndroidRuntime(1052):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-25 05:21:04.867: E/AndroidRuntime(1052):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
03-25 05:21:04.867: E/AndroidRuntime(1052):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-25 05:21:04.867: E/AndroidRuntime(1052):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-25 05:21:04.867: E/AndroidRuntime(1052):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
03-25 05:21:04.867: E/AndroidRuntime(1052):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
03-25 05:21:04.867: E/AndroidRuntime(1052):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-25 05:21:04.867: E/AndroidRuntime(1052): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-25 05:21:04.867: E/AndroidRuntime(1052):     at com.example.kei.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:18)
03-25 05:21:04.867: E/AndroidRuntime(1052):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
03-25 05:21:04.867: E/AndroidRuntime(1052):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
03-25 05:21:04.867: E/AndroidRuntime(1052):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
03-25 05:21:04.867: E/AndroidRuntime(1052):     ... 11 more
03-25 05:33:23.686: E/Trace(1694): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
03-25 05:33:23.718: D/AndroidRuntime(1694): Shutting down VM
03-25 05:33:23.718: W/dalvikvm(1694): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa6246288)
03-25 05:33:23.722: E/AndroidRuntime(1694): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-25 05:33:23.722: E/AndroidRuntime(1694): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.kei/com.example.kei.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-25 05:33:23.722: E/AndroidRuntime(1694):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
03-25 05:33:23.722: E/AndroidRuntime(1694):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
03-25 05:33:23.722: E/AndroidRuntime(1694):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
03-25 05:33:23.722: E/AndroidRuntime(1694):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
03-25 05:33:23.722: E/AndroidRuntime(1694):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-25 05:33:23.722: E/AndroidRuntime(1694):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-25 05:33:23.722: E/AndroidRuntime(1694):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
03-25 05:33:23.722: E/AndroidRuntime(1694):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-25 05:33:23.722: E/AndroidRuntime(1694):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-25 05:33:23.722: E/AndroidRuntime(1694):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
03-25 05:33:23.722: E/AndroidRuntime(1694):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
03-25 05:33:23.722: E/AndroidRuntime(1694):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-25 05:33:23.722: E/AndroidRuntime(1694): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-25 05:33:23.722: E/AndroidRuntime(1694):     at com.example.kei.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:23)
03-25 05:33:23.722: E/AndroidRuntime(1694):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
03-25 05:33:23.722: E/AndroidRuntime(1694):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
03-25 05:33:23.722: E/AndroidRuntime(1694):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
03-25 05:33:23.722: E/AndroidRuntime(1694):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: Just remove the static from the `AppSingleton` class. Simple create class and make its variable static only.

Comment: `correctChoice1` is not initialized. Replace `correctChoice1.findViewById(R.id.correct1);` with `correctChoice1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.correct1);`

Comment: Radiobutton TypeCasting error.

Comment: thank you sirs for the answers i appreciate it very much, im a beginner with android thank you!! ill try this thanks again

Comment: @GrIsHu pls help when i remove the static the AppSingleton.score++; give an error saying remove final.. i remove it and it says remove static, the error just goes in circles

Comment: @JosePerez Make the variable as `public static final int score= 0;`

Comment: @GrIsHu thank you i tried what you said.. now i have last queston, there are 5 activities 1 qeustion/activity, if the user picks correctly static int increments to 1.. but now how do i stop it to increment 5 times? i am getting 11/5 results, i dont know what to do.. even if i exit the app it still does not return to 0/5

Comment: Are you trying to say that you want your variable to increament upto 5 only ? @JosePerez

Comment: @GrIsHu yes you are very correct

Comment: Keeps on checking your variable value each time before increment and as it comes to 5 just do not increment it. Make the if condition and check for the variable value is 5 or not. If it reached to 5 then just  do not allow to increment anymore.

Comment: @GrIsHu sorry for asking again, will this do? if(AppSingleton.score == 5){
     AppSingleton.score = 0;
    }else{
     AppSingleton.score++;
    }

Comment: Yes, This is also fine. @JosePerez

Comment: @GrIsHu thank you very much for helping me :) i dont know how to thank you enough for your patience

Comment: @JosePerez you are welcome. Always feels great to help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to initialize your `RadioButton` as below:

```
 correctChoice1= (RadioButton )findViewById(R.id.correct1);
    correctChoice1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
          if(AppSingleton.score <=5)
            AppSingleton.score++;
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Page_two.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace `correctChoice1.findViewById(R.id.correct1);` with

```
correctChoice1 = (RadioButton )findViewById(R.id.correct1);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your radio button declaration was wrong:

do like this;

```
RadioButton correctChoice1;

correctChoice1 = (RadioButton).findViewById(R.id.correct1);
```